# Python-django, pycharm. Как найти нужную html страницу в проекте?

Tags: python, html, django

Пользуюсь командой `./manage.py show_urls | grep catalog/product`

получаю вывод

```
/catalog/product/<pk>/  agora.optima.product.views.product_detail_dispatcher    product_detail
```

Вот как это найти? Нужно отредачить страницу карточки продукта.

Понимаю вопрос какой-то сырой и сухой.

Answer (score 0):

дважды нажать <kbd>shift</kbd>.

или <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>.